# Make program shutdown pause in Java

Tags: java

In Java how can we "pause" any program shutdown request and wait for a method to return before shutting down (or after a given timeout)

```
import picocli.CommandLine;
// Imports 
@CommandLine.Command(
        name = "main",
        description = "Example main command"
)
public class MainCommand implements Callable<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        
        // Register the shutdown hook
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                schedulerManager.shutdown(); // must wait for this to return or timeout
            } catch (IOException | SchedulerException e) {
                Logger.error("Scheduler shutdown failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }));
        
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);  // Sleep for 1 second.
        }
    }

}
```

The shutdown method in the scheduler here will first attempt to persist jobs into the database:

```
public void shutdown() throws SchedulerException, IOException {
    persistSchedulerState();
    shutdownScheduler();
}
```

This is where it fails, the database is unable to persists since the streams have been closed.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24313507/2996452 - so basically wait for the other task to complete with `Thread.join()`

Comment: Shutdown hooks must not engage in time-intensive operations of any kind. This is stated clearly in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From java 8 you can use [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) to do this. Generally you want to do some action, and the main program should wait for the result.

If you don’t want to return anything from your callback function and just want to run some piece of code after the completion of the Future, then you can use thenAccept() and thenRun() methods. These methods are consumers and are often used as the last callback in the callback chain.

`CompletableFuture.thenAccept()` takes a `Consumer<T>` and returns `CompletableFuture<Void>`. It has access to the result of the `CompletableFuture` on which it is attached.

in your case you can do something like below:

// thenAccept() example

```
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        return schedulerManager.shutdown();
   }).thenAccept(product -> {
        System.out.println("Scheduler manager is down!";)
    });
```

Here you can see some more examples - [click](https://www.callicoder.com/java-8-completablefuture-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0):

You can't prevent closing the streams during JVM shutdown. And the shutdown hook is not the right place to persist job state. You will never know which moment of the processing has been interrupted.

My proposal is to persist the job state prior to processing using state like `JOB_STARTED`. And persist again after the processing with `JOB_SUCCESSFUL`. This way if the application has been closed in the middle of processing you will know which jobs need to be restarted.

BTW this is how `Spring Batch` handles job state.

Additionally you can implement a REST endpoint using Spring Boot MVC. Endpoint like `shutdown` can check if any jobs are still running, wait until completed and then exit application.